# Expected index of the first job candidate that is better than the very first candidate interviewed (My alternative approach doesn't match solution)

Tags: probability, expected-value

**Problem**

> Job candidates $C_1, C_2, ...$ are interviewed one by one, and the interviewer
>   compares them and keeps an updated list of rankings (if $n$ candidates have
>   been interviewed so far, this is a list of the $n$ candidates, from best to worst).
>
> Assume that there is no limit on the number of candidates available, that for
>   any $n$ the candidates $C_1, C_2, ...,C_n$  are equally likely to arrive in any order, and that there are no ties in the rankings given by the interview.
>
> Let $X$ be the index of the first candidate to come along who ranks as better
>   than the very first candidate $C_1$ (so $C_X$ is better than $C_1$, but the candidates after $1$ but prior to $X$ (if any) are worse than $C_1$. For example, if $C_2$ and $C_3$
>   are worse than $C_1$ but $C_4$ is better than $C_1$, then $X = 4$. All $4!$ orderings of the first $4$ candidates are equally likely, so it could have happened that the first candidate was the best out of the first $4$ candidates, in which case $X >4$.
>
> What is $E(X)$ (which is a measure of how long, on average, the interviewer
>   needs to wait to find someone better than the very first candidate)?

**My question 1**

Let's say there are only $2$ job candidates in the entire world.

Then is the pmf of $X$ (which is the index of the first candidate better than the first), something like $X=2$ with probability $1/2$ and $X=$ 'wait forever' with probability $1/2$? So $X$ is Bernoulli? Is that correct?

**My quesiton 2**

I understand the book solution but what is wrong with my alternative approach of finding the pmf and doing the typical expected value formula?

Let $X = $ the index of the first person better than the very first

Then $P(X=n) = \frac{(n-2)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ where the reasoning is the last person has to be the best and the first person has to be the second best.

Therefore

$$E[X] = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n(n-1)} = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...$$

but this does not equal the book solution of $1+1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...$

I'm thinking my pmf is wrong or perhaps this has something to do with St Petersburg Paradox? Thank you for your help and patience.

**Book solution**

[image]

Comment: In your question 1, $X$ is not Bernoulli, since $X$ can take the values $2$ and $+\infty$ while a Bernoulli random variable can only take the values $0$ and $1$.  The question of whether the second candidate is better than the first *is* Bernoulli

Comment: @Henry thanks that helps and is clear.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but also in my head, the fact that every arrangement is equally likely makes me believe that any given candidate should have $p = 0.5$ of beating the first candidate. The fact that $C_1$ is currently in first shouldn't really make a difference. So, why can't we just denote $X \sim FS(0.5) + 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches give the same answer, though this is obscured by the fact this answer is $+\infty$ and so it seems that the book has an extra term

Let's illustrate this by limiting the game to end at a maximum of $6$. So you have a random variable which takes the value $2$ with probability $\frac12$, the value $3$ with probability $\frac16$, the value $4$ with probability $\frac1{12}$, the value $5$ with probability $\frac1{20}$ and the value $6$ with the remaining probability $\frac15$

- Then you would say that the expected value was $2 \times \frac12+3 \times \frac16 + 4 \times \frac1{12}+ 5 \times \frac1{20} + 6 \times \frac1{5}= 1 +\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac65$
- while the book would say the expectation was $1+1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15$

These are clearly the same total even if the sums are slightly different at the beginning and end.  They each add up to $\frac{197}{60} \approx 3.2833$

Comment: Thanks for your help Henry. Question for you... if the max is set to $6$ how would you define $X$? Originally $X$ is defined as the index of the first candidate better than the first. But it seems that with the max set to $6$ you are defining $X$ as the best candidate since the first except if $X =$ the max then it could be ambiguous if the max is better than the first...

Comment: @HJ_beginner Suppose you adopt the strategy of looking at the first candidate then picking the next candidate better than the first, or the sixth candidate if none of $2,3,4,5$ are better than the first.  Then $X$ is the number of people you see in total and $E[X]=3.2833$ the expected number you see

Comment: Interesting... that makes sense. The original definition of $X$ assumes an infinite population... changing the problem to have a finite population (ie 6) means that $X$ must slightly change since it's not the same problem.

Comment: if there is no limit on the number of candidates available, then $P(X=6) = \dfrac{1}{6\cdot 5}$. But, if we limit the game to end at a maximum of 6 then, what we are essentially saying is that $P(X=6| X\neq 2,3,4,5) = 1$ (and hence,  $P(X=6) = \dfrac{1}{5}$)